# How can I allow connections only from certain hostnames (IPs may change due to dynamic DNS)?

Tags: networking, firewall, connection, restricted-access

I want to allow connections only from certain hostnames instead of by specific IP (the hostnames are defined by dynamic DNS).

For example, home.no-ip.org, mobile.no-ip.org, etc.

Is this possible out-of-the-box with something like [ufw](/questions/tagged/ufw) or [firewalld](/questions/tagged/firewalld)? If not, what might a solution look like - should some script do an nslookup on the hostname every X often, then drop & add firewall rules?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with ip tables.

Set of commands will be something like this

clear existing chains

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

allow all ICMP

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

access from `home.no-ip.org` and port `80`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: home.something.com" --algo bm -j ACCEPT
```

then rule for all incoming traffic from `mobile.no-ip.org`

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -s mobile.no-ip.org -j ACCEPT
```

allow SSH for any

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

deny all accept above rules

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

save

```
sudo service iptables save
```

I'm not sure that this will work, but you can try :)
This is only example of rules and can use them like template .